# How to trigger a private web-service http_request in a way that is compatible with most domain hosts?

Tags: php, jquery, web-services, wordpress

My customers are developers of blogs and other websites. These websites are hosted on a wide variety of different sites, e.g. wordpress.org, dreamhost, etc.

I would like to be able to give them a bit of code (eg some javascript and/or php) that causes a message to be sent to my "tracker server" whenever one of their pages is visited (e.g. an http_get_request). The message must include a *secret unique ID*, that uniquely identifies / confirms that the message is authentically from a visit to that customer's website.

My current strategy is to give the customers a snippet of jQuery to put at the top of their template to (at the right time) perform an http_request to http_request a `notify_tracker_server.php` file that is also located on their server. The .php The secret unique ID would be inside that php file, so a visitor to the customer's website would never see it.

Is this a good way to do things?

My concerns are :

1. In general, do wordpress.org and other popular hosting options allow .php files to be added to their sites?
2. In general, do they allow for http_requests to be made from their server to other servers?

Or more broadly, is there a better way to do this? For instance, is it possible to do so without using PHP (or any other server-side script), but still keeping the unique ID secret.

Comment: I disagree that this question is primarily opinion based. I am looking for a best-practice, one that is objectively measurable, e.g. in terms of being maximally compatible with different hosts. I am also looking for factual information in the question "is it possible to do this without using PHP?"

Answer (score 1):

1. Wordpress.org lets you edit your page template.  You could include a PHP snippet there that could be called on page loads.
2. It would be host dependendent if they let PHP fopen other hosts or fget them.

You could certainly write a PHP snippet that outputs a simple javascript that makes a hit to your home server with your 'secret' info.

Since I doubt you are using this to protect anything that really requires encryption, just base64 encode the 'secret' string and use that in the url.  You could even put it like this in javascript.

```
<?php
 $mysecret='site101.com';
 $encoded=base64_encode($mysecret);
  echo'
   <script src="http://www.homeserver.com/scripts/mytracker.php?site='.$encoded.'"></script>
  ';


?>
```

then on your mytracker.php

```
$decoded=base64_decode($_POST['site']);
echo $decoded  ( 'site101.com' )
```

- Edit -
  You could forgo the PHP include totally and generate the  tag in advance.

  ```
  `<script src="http://www.homeserver.com/scripts/mytracker.php?site=c2l0ZTEwMS5jb20="></script>`
  ```

Comment: I can't have the message be visible to visitors of the customer's site, even if it is encrypted, because if it were, the encrypted message could be sent to my "tracking server" by a spoofer. I think both of your suggestions would let the encrypted message be seen by visitors to the site. No?

Comment: You could check the PHP variable $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] of the calling user.  That would be the IP of the user on the page that script is on.  Then just rate limit how many hits or points or whatever you are tracking per IP.  That way if the same user refreshed the same page 1000 times in an hour.  You would still only count that one time if you wanted.

Comment: Do you know, or do you know how I can find out if php's fopen() is generally available or not among the most popular hosting providers?